# Can't modify logical and (&&) scalar assignment

Tags: perl

I am getting this error below when testing the building out of a CGI form I am doing.  I am trying to verify that the user entered in data in the CGI form and also that the value is submitted.  Is there something I am missing?

Regards,

```
C:\xampp\cgi-bin>perl create_report.cgi
Can't modify logical and (&&) in scalar assignment at create_report.cgi line 105
, near "'Submitted')"
```

Code:

```
if (defined $user_entry && $user_entry='Submitted') {
sub show_form {
    print qq{<form name="input" action="create_report.cgi" method="post">\n};
    print qq{<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black" cellpadding='2' cellspacing="0">\n};
    print qq{<tr>};
    print qq{<td align="right">Please enter the description of the Report you  are copying</td};
    print qq{</tr>\n};
    print qq{<tr>};
    print qq{<td align="left"><input type"text" width="7" name="spns"  value=""};
    print qq{<BR>Be sure to use just one or two words to find the report.  Like "Mortgage Summary".</td>};
    print qq{</table><center><input type="submit" value="Submitted"></center></form>\n};
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have two errors here. Firstly you're using the assignment operator (`=`) where you really want the string equality operator (`eq`).

But secondly, you have a problem with the precedence. You want your boolean condition to be parsed as:

```
(defined $user) && ($entry = 'Submitted')
```

But actually, it's being parsed as:

```
defined ( ( $user && $entry ) = 'Submitted')
```

I think that makes it clear why you're getting the error that you're seeing.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the assignment operator `=` to try to check the value of `$user_entry`, use `eq` to compare two strings in Perl:

```
if (defined $user_entry && $user_entry eq 'Submitted')
```

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing `=` assignment and `eq` string equivalence operator here. Use `eq` (and see more on Perl operators in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)). Placing sub definition inside an `if` isn't good idea either.

Comment: hmm..okay I have the sub main routine out side of the if loop; I can certainly place that sub show_form routine outside of the if loop as well.  Thanks Oleg

Answer (score 3):

You are doing assignment instead of comparison because `=` denotes assignment in Perl, the correct operator to use in numeric context is `==`.  However, your are doing a string comparison so you should be using `eq`. See bellow:

```
if (defined $user_entry && $user_entry eq 'Submitted')
```

Answer (score 2):

So exactly what are you trying to do? I take it you want to see if `$user_entry` is defined and if it is, that `$user_entry` is set to "Submitted"

In this case, you're using the wrong operator. The `=` is attempting to set `$user_entry` to the string *Submitted*. You want to do this:

```
if (defined $user_entry && ( $user_entry eq "Submitted" ) ) {
```

And note the use of Parentheses! Which brings us to the other issue:

#### Operator Precidence

This is a tricky one. Basically the `&&` operator has a higher precedence than the `defined` function because the `defined` operator is operating on the completed expression. Thus your statement is actually being translated as this:

```
if { defined [$user_entry && ($user_entry='Submitted') ] }
```

(**NOTE**: *I'm using different style of parentheses is order to see what is matched with what. This is bad Perl. In Perl, you would use the `(...)` parentheses only*)

This is because the precedence order is:

- Setting the value first (the `=` operator)
- Then the `&&` operator
- Then `defined`

To do what you want:

```
if ( defined( $user_entry ) && $user_entry eq 'Submitted' )
```

Or, might as well parenthesize everything to be absolutely clear:

```
if ( defined( $user_entry ) && ( $user_entry eq 'Submitted' ) ) {
```

I believe that the precedence of `&&` and `||` are just plain flat-out broken. These operators simply don't do what you want them to do 90% of the time. Instead, I use `and` and `or` which do exactly what I expect them to do:

```
if defined $user_entry and $user_entry eq 'Submitted ) {
```

This precedence order is:

- `defined $user_entry` is checked. If `$user_entry` is defined...
- $user_entry is compared to `'Submitted'` for truth
- Finally, the `and` operator is executed

Which finally brings us to one more thing:

#### Always use `use strict` and `use warnings`

If you had `use warnings;` in your program, you would have gotten this error:

```
Found = in conditional, should be == at at create_report.cgi line 105.
```

That would have pointed out to you that you were attempting to set the value of `$user_entry` instead of checking the equality.

Comment: "Basically the && operator has a higher precedence than the defined function" is not true. See `perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e'defined $x && f()'`. The precedence problem is that `=` has lower precedence than `&&`. The parens you asked the reader to note are superfluous.